# Unity C# - Screen Space - Overlay Canvas Input.mousePosition is way off, even after applying the canvasScale?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, camera

[image]
[image]

The image with the compass and other UI is actually the top left corner and the tooltip is spawning outside the canvas as you can see.
Ive been searching for hours now on how to fix this:

Im using a Screen Space - Overlay Canvas.

Setting an UI Elements Anchored position through code to make it follow the mouse.

```
        Vector2 anchoredPosition = Input.mousePosition;

        rectTransform.anchoredPosition = anchoredPosition;
```

However this doesnt retun the right position.

I tried `Input.mousePosition / Canvas.scaleFactor;`

And I also tried `Input.mousePosition / canvasRectTransform.localScale.x;`

And finally `Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition);`

But again, no luck at all... Free Aspect doesnt fix it either.
Changing the reference width and height doesnt fix it, setting from 16:9 to 16:10 does nothing to help me either.

The UI element is always way outside the actual canvas (camera view).

The UI element itself is a RectTransform with size of 1,1 with the anchor in the middle. Testing it by setting element position to 0,0 shows it perfectly centered.

Can someone please help me?

Thank you.

EDIT:
I got it to work by changing the reference resolution on the Canvas until I saw the canvas scale was exactly 1,1,1. Ofcourse I dont want this reference resolution, but atleast it tells us that it has to do with that:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Mouse position is read on screen coordinates. Canvas position is a combination of the canvas reference resolution, your actual screen size, and the canvas’ scale factor.

Say your screen is 1080p and your canvas reference resolution is 1080p. And the canvas is set to fill your screen. The coordinates will directly line up between mouse position and canvas position.

With different screen resolutions than the reference resolution, this Gets more complex to calculate. But there’s a handy function to handle this for you.

```
RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle.html